# How to replace NAs of a variable with values from another dataframe

Tags: r, match, dplyr, na

i hope this one isn´t stupid.

I have two dataframes with Variables ID and gender/sex. In df1, there are NAs. In df2, the variable is complete. I want to complete the column in df1 with the values from df2.
(In df1 the variable is called "gender". In df2 it is called "sex".)

Here is what i tried so far:

```
#example-data
ID<-seq(1,30,by=1)
df1<-as.data.frame(ID)
df2<-df1
df1$gender<-c(NA,"2","1",NA,"2","2","2","2","2","2",NA,"2","1","1",NA,"2","2","2","2","2","1","2","2",NA,"2","2","2","2","2",NA)
df2$sex<-c("2","2","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2")


#Approach 1: 
NAs.a <- is.na(df1$gender)
df1$gender[NAs.a] <- df2[match(df1$ID[NAs.a], df2$ID),]$sex

#Approach 2 (i like dplyr a lot, perhaps there´s a way to use it):
library("dplyr")
temp<-df2 %>% select(ID,gender)

#EDIT:
#df<-left_join(df1$gender,df2$gender, by="ID") 
 df<-left_join(df1,df2, by="ID")
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, i´ve met this problem:`table(Datensatz$gender, useNA="always")` brings 0/1/NA  then `table(sampleframe$sex) ` has 0/1. So how come 
  
`> Datensatz$gender[NAs.a] <- sampleframe[match(Datensatz$ID[NAs.a], sampleframe$ID),]$sex
> table(Datensatz$gender, useNA="always")` brings me 4x the value "2"?

   0    1       2   <NA> 
 279  294    4    0

Comment: Actually your first approach with `match` should be very efficient, why don't you like it?

Comment: i like it, but with my data (not the example-data) i´m not getting values of 0 and 1, but also 2 (4 times). I don´t have a clue where this goes wrong, because both columns only consist of 0 and 1.

Comment: Did you try `df1[df2, sex := i.sex][is.na(gender), gender := sex][]` like I've suggsted in comments? That will show you both columns so you can compare and see if everything match correctly. It will also modify `df1` by reference.

Comment: yes, but i get this error: Error in `:=`(sex, i.sex) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: You need to do `setkey(setDT(df1), ID)` first of course....

Comment: I found the error. In df2 sex was a factor, not numeric. When this factor is converted to numeric it gets the values 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1 (because zero and one are the factor levels 1 and 2). I just have to convert the factor to numeric like this df2$sex<-df2$sex<-as.numeric(levels(df2$sex))[as.integer(df2$sex)] and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick solution using `data.table`s binary join this will join *only* `gender` with `sex` and leave all the rest of the columns untouched

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), ID)
df1[df2, gender := i.sex][]
#     ID gender
#  1:  1      2
#  2:  2      2
#  3:  3      1
#  4:  4      2
#  5:  5      2
#  6:  6      2
#  7:  7      2
#  8:  8      2
#  9:  9      2
# 10: 10      2
# 11: 11      2
# 12: 12      2
# 13: 13      1
# 14: 14      1
# 15: 15      2
# 16: 16      2
# 17: 17      2
# 18: 18      2
# 19: 19      2
# 20: 20      2
# 21: 21      1
# 22: 22      2
# 23: 23      2
# 24: 24      2
# 25: 25      2
# 26: 26      2
# 27: 27      2
# 28: 28      2
# 29: 29      2
# 30: 30      2
```

Comment: Does this only replace the NAs, or does it replace the whole column?

Comment: If you want to replace only `NA`s in gender, you could do something like `df1[df2, sex := i.sex][is.na(gender), gender := sex][]`. Though the `dplyr` answer also joins over whole column an it seems like your were alright with that

Answer (score 2):

This would probably be the simplest with base R.

```
idx <- is.na(df1$gender)
df1$gender[idx] = df2$sex[idx]
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn´t seem to work when both vectors have a different length.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
df1 %>% select(ID) %>% left_join(df2, by = "ID")
#   ID sex
#1   1   2
#2   2   2
#3   3   1
#4   4   2
#5   5   2
#6   6   2
#.. ..
```

This assumes - as in the example - that all ID's from df1 are also present in df2 and have a sex/gender information there.

---

If you have other columns in your data you could also try this instead:

```
df1 %>% select(-gender) %>% left_join(df2[c("ID", "sex")], by = "ID")
```

Comment: @user2982730, did you use the data from the example? I didnt get any errors with dplyr 0.4.1